# Default Object.rotation's axis of rotation (Three.js)

Tags: three.js

Does changing the value of an object's rotation property rotate the object about the world axes or the object's axes? For eg

```
object.rotation.x += 2
```

Will this rotate the object about the world X axis or the object's X axis?
I tried the following example :

```
var materials = []; 
materials.push( [ new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff0000 } ) ] );
materials.push( [ new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff0000 } ) ] );
materials.push( [ new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } ) ] );
materials.push( [ new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } ) ] );
materials.push( [ new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x0000ff } ) ] );
materials.push( [ new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x0000ff } ) ] );

object = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.CubeGeometry( 20, 20, 20, 1, 1, 1, materials ), new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial() );

object.position.x = 0;
object.position.y = 0;
object.position.z = 0;

object.rotation.x = 0;
object.rotation.y = 0;
object.rotation.z = 0;

object.scale.x = 1;
object.scale.y = 1;
object.scale.z = 1;

scene.add( object );

After i have added the object to the scene i tried the following - 
object.rotation.x += Math.PI/4;
object.rotation.y += Math.PI/4;
object.rotation.z += Math.PI/4;
```

Until now the object rotates with respect to its own X,Y and Z axes.
but doing:

```
object.rotation.x += Math.Pi/4;
```

now rotates the object 45 degrees about the World X axis instead of the object's X axis.

Answer (score 0):

The rotations are in local space. However, they are evaluated in a specific order which you can set yourself. The `object.rotation` property is an [`Euler`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/math/Euler), and as you can read in the description of the [`order`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/math/Euler.order)-property:

> The order in which to apply rotations. Default is 'XYZ', which means
>   that the object will first be rotated around its X axis, then its Y
>   axis and finally its Z axis. Other possibilities are: 'YZX', 'ZXY',
>   'XZY', 'YXZ' and 'ZYX'. These must be in upper case.
>   Three.js uses intrinsic Tait-Bryan angles. This means that rotations
>   are performed with respect to the local coordinate system. That is,
>   **for order 'XYZ', the rotation is first around the local-X axis (which
>   is the same as the world-X axis)**, then around local-Y (which may now
>   be different from the world Y-axis), then local-Z (which may be
>   different from the world Z-axis).

(Emphasis added by me).

Consider the following example, every cube is updated with the same y-axis rotation. In every case the rotation is happening around the y-axis in local space, but:

- The first cube has not been rotated in any other axis, making its
  local space axis the same as the world space axis.
- The second cube has been rotated around its x-axis, which means that
  the y-axis is also rotated.
- The third cube has also been rotated, but the *order* of rotation is
  changed so that the y-axis rotation happens first, while it is still the      same as the world y-axis, and the rotation around x happens afterward.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(10, 2, 20, 40);
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas });
const light = new THREE.PointLight();
light.position.set(0, 5, 10)
scene.add(light);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 25);

const material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial();
const geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
const cube1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
const cube2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
const cube3 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
cube1.position.set(-2, 0, 0);
cube2.position.set( 0, 0, 0);
cube3.position.set( 2, 0, 0);
scene.add(cube1);
scene.add(cube2);
scene.add(cube3);

//The first cube is not rotated
cube1.rotation.set(0, 0, 0);
//The second cube is rotated pi/4 rad around X
cube2.rotation.set(Math.PI/4, 0, 0);
//The third cube is rotated pi/4 rad around X
//AND the rotation order is set to YXZ to make the y-rotation happen first
cube3.rotation.set(Math.PI/4, 0, 0);
cube3.rotation.order = "YXZ";

let t0 = performance.now();
function update(){
 const t1 = performance.now();
 const rotation = 0.001 * (t1 - t0);
  
  cube1.rotation.y += rotation;
  cube2.rotation.y += rotation;
  cube3.rotation.y += rotation;
  
  renderer.render(scene, camera);

 t0 = t1;
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

update();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/92/three.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: rotation object looks like

`object.rotation = Euler {_x: 0, _y: 0, _z: 0, _order: "XYZ", onChangeCallback: ƒ}`.

Even if I do `object.rotation.set(0, 0, Math.PI / 2)` 
i.e `object.rotation =Euler {_x: 0, _y: 0, _z: 1.5707963267948966, _order: "XYZ", onChangeCallback: ƒ}`
object is getting rotated in world Z axis

Comment: Well, if you do `object.rotation.set(0,0,z)` you are resetting the x and y values to 0. You can do the rotation as you did in the question by `object.rotation.z += Math.Pi/4;`, just be aware that they evaluate in the specific order set by `order`.

Comment: I have tried every possible order 'YZX', 'ZXY', 'XZY', 'YXZ' and 'ZYX', 
`a.rotation.order  = "ORDER"`,  after which I did `object.rotation.z += Math.PI/4`, the object is rotating in World Z axis only.

Comment: @sarthaksaxena I have added an example which I hope will clear things up a bit.

Comment: thanks a lot, understood what the problem with my code is.